# sprite won't move left or right in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to move a sprite (called Player) to the left or right by pressing the arrow keys. The movement to the right or left would be made by changing the center of the rectangle of the sprite.  As you might be able to see, I am trying to add/subtract 8 from the sprite's x coordinates in order to move it right or left. However, the sprite doesn't move when I hit an arrow key. How can I fix this?

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import pygame as pg


# set the width and height of the window
width = 800
height = 370
groundThickness = 30
pheight = 50
pwidth = 50
playerx = 0+pwidth
playery = height-groundThickness-pheight/2
fps = 30
# define colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
red = (5, 35, 231)
# initialize pygame 
pygame.init()

# initialize pygame sounds
pygame.mixer.init()
# create window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("my game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image = pygame.Surface((pwidth, pheight))
            self.image.fill(red)
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
            self.rect.center = (playerx, playery)

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

# Game loop
running = True
x_change = 0
while running:
    # keep loop running at the right speed
    clock.tick(fps)
    # Process input (events)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                print("left")
                x_change = -8
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                print("right")
                x_change = 8
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
        print(x_change)
        playerx += x_change
        all_sprites.update()



    #ground
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,255,0), ((0, height-groundThickness), (width, groundThickness)))



    # Update
    all_sprites.update()



    # Draw / render
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    # AFTER drawing everything, flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've never altered the position of the sprite `player`.
How do you expect it to move?
All you've done is to change the value of your local variable `playerx`, but you've never pushed that change back into the sprite object.

Start by adding the middle line below:

```
    playerx += x_change
    player.rect.center = (playerx, playery)
    all_sprites.update()
```

See how that alters things?  Can you take it from there?

Comment: what that does is makes one side bigger but doesn't move the sprite as a whole.

Comment: would there be a better way of moving the sprite; instead of moving the center?

Comment: Yes.  See any of the myriad on-line tutorials.

Comment: *"what that does is makes one side bigger but doesn't move the sprite as a whole."* @CJPeine you have to fill the screen with a background color or an image every frame to clear it, and then redraw everything else.  ---  I'd also recommend adding an `update` method to your `Player` sprite and put the movement code `playerx += x_change`, etc. into this method. The `update` method will get called by `all_sprites.update()` in the main loop.

Comment: ok,  so I go the sprite to move. how would I be able to hold down an arrow key and continuously move the sprite?

Comment: Again, see any of the myriad on-line tutorials.  That's beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, as the intro tour showed you.

Answer (score 0):

Filling the screen with your background color or image will also be needed to keep your screen updated with the current position of the moving sprite. The following command will be added at the top of your draw/render section of the game loop:

```
screen.fill(black)
```